# How to add title of a paper in the reference section?

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

The reference section is not showing the title of the paper. What changes shall I make so that the paper now includes the title `Fast integration of rapidly oscillatory functions` as well.

[image]

**main.tex**

```
\input{preamble}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}

\begin{document}
\title{Reference check}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
    I want to include this reference \citet{levin96}.
    
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{References}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

**ref.bib**

```
@article{levin96,
title={Fast integration of rapidly oscillatory functions}, 
author={D. Levin}, 
journal={J. Comp. Appl. Math.}, 
year={1996}, 
volume={67}, 
pages={95-101},
}
```

**preamble.tex**

```
\documentclass[
superscriptaddress,
aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line

```
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
```

in `main.tex`.
[image]

```
% main.tex
\input{preamble}
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}

\begin{document}
\title{Reference check}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
    I want to include this reference \citet{levin96}.
    
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{References}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also how to remove the styling in the text. Like bold and italic characters?

Comment: @Formal_this Which styling, at which places? Can you point it out in the images above? For section headings and the like it is defined by the class, and anywhere else the user explicitly requests it with `\textbf`, `\bfseries`, `\emph` etc.

Comment: I was talking about the reference [1] line only. We see a bold font after the journal name `J. Comp. Appl. Math` after this there is a bold font `67`

Comment: @Formal_this I wouldn't tinker with the bibliography style, as the point of standardized bib styles is that people can decipher the bib entry. It is commonly agreed that the bold number is the volume. Otherwise you have a series of numbers and don't know which is which.

Comment: @Formal_this If you absolutely want to get rid of the boldface characters without editing the bibliography style directly, add the line `\renewcommand\textbf[1]{#1}` immediately before `\bibliography{...}`. Likewise, use `\renewcommand\emph[1]{#1}` to get rid of italics. But I advise against it, see above ...